# MKMapView to UIImage with Overlays

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit, mkmapsnapshotter

How do you take an UIImage of MKMapView with overlays like MKPolylines? I tried renderInContext and MKMapSnapshotter but none include the map and its overlays in the produced image. renderInContext doesn't work in iOS 7 at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation for the MKMapSnapshotter class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapSnapshotter_class/Reference/Reference.html), overlays and annotations are not included in the produced snapshot. According to the [documentation for the MKMapSnapshot class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapSnapshot_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013271), you can use `pointForCoordinate` to manually draw the overlays and annotations on the snapshot image yourself.

Also, you might want to post your renderInContext code.

--Edit--

In iOS 7, they added the following three new methods, which you might want to try alongside the renderInContext method:

```
– snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates: // Captures view as a snapshot view, which may allow you to draw an image using renderInContet.
– resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets: // Similar to the previous method, except using a rect.
– drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: // Draws the entire view hierarchy, so this may allow you to capture subviews.
```

Comment: My question is is there any other way to do it besides these two methods.

Comment: @smartfuse See my edited answer. Also, please post your renderInContext method code. I'm using it in iOS 7 (albeit, not with a map view) and it's working fine for me.

Comment: I decided to just draw the lines manually in the UIImage. Thanks though.